# Can Einstein Studio be enabled in scratch orgs?

Tags: einstein, datacloud

We'd like to investigate the Bring Your Own Model feature of Salesforce Einstein. From what I can tell, this is part of Einstein Studio, which is a part of Data Cloud. I can't find any documentation of how to enable either Data Cloud or Einstein Studio in scratch orgs. I don't see any option in the scratch org, even when created as Enterprise Edition.

Is it possible to enable Einstein Studio in a scratch org? If not, how can we evaluate the BYOM feature of Einstein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in Scratch orgs.

The feature is related to the Data Cloud as you mentioned. You will need a Data Cloud enabled org which you can spin from your Partner Hub. Then there are extra permissions.

The best way to get these for trial is by reaching to your Account Executives.

Comment: Thank you Mohith.